# Redirecting a locally mounted Windows SMB share (CIFS) to a Windows Terminal Server session

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, remote-desktop, cifs

I have been living in the Linux world only two months so far and have hit a problem with the above mentioned task, now explained in more detail:

Our company has two Windows Terminal Servers to which the different clients connect from different branch offices. I have now tried to incorporate a Lubuntu 12.10 PC which is supposed to solely act as a Remote Desktop client.

As RDP-Client I am using **freerdp** (xfreerdp) which works like a charm, but when I try to access the redirected mounted windows share I get the following error:

```
Open Folder (Title)
\\tsclient\Office is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
```

The syntax I use for the connection:

```
xfreerdp --sec rdp --no-nla --ignore-certificate -g 1680x1050 -f --plugin rdpdr --data printer:HPLJ5200_SMB:"HP LaserJet 5" --plugin rdpdr --data disk:Transfer:/home/apl03/Transfer --plugin rdpdr --data disk:Office:/media/Office -- 192.168.0.101
```

As you can see I am redirecting a printer and two folders. I can successfully print with the printer from the Windows terminal session, and I can access the folder `/home/apl03/Transfer` without any problems.

Accessing the second folder, `/media/Office`, does not work.

`/media/Office` is a share of the local file server of that branch office. The user apl03 has an account in the local Active Directory (AD) and file access from Lubuntu itself to the share works without any problems (read & write).

The share is mounted in `/etc/fstab` via:

```
//192.168.1.1/OFFICE /media/Office cifs credentials=/home/apl03/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

The permissions of `/media/Office` on the Lubuntu file system are as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root    0 Mär 27 15:26 Office
```

It may well be a permission issue but I don't know where else to look. Both in the filesystem and in fstab I made the folder available.

I am grateful for any suggestions or pointers.

**Update**

The log output on the terminal:

```
loading plugin rdpdr
connected to 192.168.0.103:3389
null server certificate
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--plugin.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--plugin.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load --plugin/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to load /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/rdpdr.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/rdpdr.so: undefined symbol: DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load rdpdr/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--data.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--data.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load --data/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--plugin.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--plugin.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load --plugin/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to load /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/rdpdr.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/rdpdr.so: undefined symbol: DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load rdpdr/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--data.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--data.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load --data/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/-plugin.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/-plugin.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load -plugin/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to load /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/rdpdr.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/rdpdr.so: undefined symbol: DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load rdpdr/DeviceServiceEntry
freerdp_load_library_symbol: failed to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--data.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/freerdp/--data.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
freerdp_load_plugin: failed to load --data/DeviceServiceEntry
registered device #1: PRN1 (type=4 id=1)
registered device #2: PRN2 (type=4 id=2)
registered device #3: Transfer (type=8 id=3)
registered device #4: Office (type=8 id=4)
```

Despite there being some strange errors access to the "Transfer" folder works just fine. If I only redirect that folder and remove the other it still gives these errors but it does work. Also the fact that all devices are logged as registered seems to indicate that the errors aren't about that.

I also tried changing the ownership of "/media/Office" to the user apl03 with no effect.

**Update**

I now managed to recreate the problem in a test environment using two laptops. Although they have the same version of Ubuntu, the same configuration for samba.conf & fstab (I checked with "diff"), the one works and the other doesn't. File ownerships and rights are the same and even the username is identical. In both cases the folder shows up in the session, but on one client it's not accessible - just like in our company.

For the fun of it I tried "**rdesktop**" instead of "freerdp" and at least in my test setup everything seems to work with that. I will check if it's the same at work. If it is I guess this can be closed and attributed to a bug in "freerdp"

For reference, this is the equivalent rdesktop command I used:

```
rdesktop -z -P -x m -a 16 -k de -g 1680x1050 -f -r disk:Transfer=/home/apl03/Transfer,Office=/media/Office 192.168.0.101
```

Comment: You may have already tried this, but swap the order of the transfer and office parameters and see if Transfer stops working and Office starts working :)

Comment: Ok, I don't think it'll make a difference but I'll try it when I'm at the office again at friday

Comment: Also, is there any output on the client terminal after running `xfreerdp`?

Comment: Yes, there a few (harmless) log messages printed on the terminal - I'll post them together with my result of the swapped parameters

Comment: I posted the log output in the question. I also tried changing the order of the mounts as well as only mounting /media/Office but it didn't change anything

Comment: You're missing a `--` before the second `-plugin` section - it means the `--data` and so on is being read as the name of a library, not an argument to the program

Comment: Oh, right. Shame on me. However strangely enough correcting it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still could not figure out why **freerdp** doesn't work on some clients. However, every client does work with **rdesktop** instead (see updates in original question). While it isn't a satisfactory solution for the original problem, using rdesktop is a workaround that meets all requirements.

Unless somebody suggests otherwise I am considering this to be a bug with freerdp.

The command that I now ultimately use:

```
rdesktop -z -P -x m -a 16 -k de -u "" -g 1680x1050 -f -r printer:HPLJ5200="HP LaserJet 5" -r printer:Brother-MFC-8370DN="HP LaserJet 5" -r disk:Transfer=/home/apl03/Transfer,Office=/media/Office 192.168.0.101
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to end all `--plugin` parts with `--` so forexample

```
--plugin rdpdr --data disk:Transfer:/home/apl03/Transfer
```

becomes

```
--plugin rdpdr --data disk:Transfer:/home/apl03/Transfer --
```

see more here https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Plugins

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my folder redirection did not work if I was using the `-g`, but using the `-f` was working great. So what I did:

Adding spaces before the `-g` did the job great here are the command lines (Replace the dots with spaces in the working):

```
nohup xfreerdp *...* -g 1600x900 -d DOMAIN  (Working)
nohup xfreerdp -g 1600x900 -d DOMAIN     (Failed)
```

Working:

```
nohup xfreerdp ... -g 1600x900 -d DOMAIN -u   USERNAME --plugin cliprdr --plugin rdpsnd --plugin rdpdr --data disk:K55A:/media/NAME_OF_FOLDER -- --ignore-certificate -z --disable-wallpaper NAME_OF SERVER:3389
```

Not working:

```
nohup xfreerdp -g 1600x900 -d DOMAIN -u   USERNAME --plugin cliprdr --plugin rdpsnd --plugin rdpdr --data disk:K55A:/media/NAME_OF_FOLDER -- --ignore-certificate -z --disable-wallpaper NAME_OF SERVER:3389
```